# How to approximate/model a speaker

Tags: speakers

I am working on driving an 8 ohms speaker. I am currently modelling(in Ltspice) it just as an 8 ohms resistor. However this is probably far from being realistic. I don't want/need too much precision however.  So how can I model a speaker with minimum complexity but also better than one single resistor?

Comment: This is easy to find using Google, for example: http://audiojudgement.com/speaker-equivalent-circuit/

Comment: [This looks interesting.](https://circuitdigest.com/electronic-circuits/simulate-speaker-with-equivalent-rlc-circuit)  No time to evaluate it and make a summary.  Maybe you could look at it and post an answer to your own question if the information in that link helps you.

Comment: Do you want to model out the speaker using a mathematical model, or do you want to do a simulation in LTSpice using a basic circuit?

Comment: @abunickabhi no, I actualy wanted something like the others linked.